# How to get multiple values for a single key in java using Properties class?

Tags: java

For eg:-
my Properties file contains the following data:
    user=system
    user=oracle
    user=xyz .
And I write the following code:-

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.*;  
public class Test 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception

FileReader reader=new FileReader("db.properties");  

Properties p=new Properties();  
p.load(reader);  

System.out.println(p.getProperty("user"));  

}  
}
```

The output I get is xyz.

How to get all the values as an output ?

Comment: Technically not possible, java.util. Properties extends HashTable, so two key with the same name(or duplicate key) not possible, Work around  - `user=oracle,xyz`

Answer (score 1):

An extension of Subhrajyoti's answer.

```
public List<String> getValues(String key) {
    String list = p.getProperty(key);
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(list.split(",")));
}
```